# Rendering Show/Hide fields with Visualforce

Tags: visualforce

I have an object with two fields which need show/hide functionality (only display FieldB is Field = x).

I believe the only way to accomplish this type of functionality is by using the render function and IF statement. (correct me if I'm wrong). But I don't want to have to use Visualforce for the whole object just for these two fields. There's a ton of Record Types and that would lead to a lot of tedious maintenance.

Is there a simple way to accomplish all of this ? Can I somehow just write a short VF page of just the fields which need it and embed it into the Page Layout ? If so, are there any other things I need to be aware of for it ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: do you want to create separate recordtype and pagelayout for this logic, then that can be done through configuration?

Comment: I only want to do it for one record type. Can I accomplish all of the necessary functionality by just embedding a small VF page with the necessary fields into the page layout of that record type ? I'd rather not have to completely abandon page layouts and use VF pages to render every field in the object.